# How to add an event listener to a rectangle drawn on a canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, event-listener

I have a canvas element, and when the page loads, an image and some shapes are drawn to the canvas. When the image is clicked, I want to trigger a function. I first tried this.

```js
const btn = ctx.drawImage(btnImg, 0, 0, 150, 100);

btn.onmousedown = function () {
  // do stuff
}
```

This didn't work. I didn't get any errors in the console either. I then tried using the `addEventListener` function.

```js
const btn = ctx.drawImage(btnImg, 0, 0, 150, 100);

btn.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  // do stuff
}, false);
```

Once again, this didn't work. Is this possible without having to use the CSS `z-index` property to float a button over the canvas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do isn't possible - at least not in such way.
The problem is that the canvas doesn't actually know about the shape of things
you draw onto. It merely knows about individual pixel color.

What you can do however is keep the bounding box - screen position and dimensions -
of your button(s) as a Path2D rectangle and use the `context.isPointInPath(path2d,x,y)` function to check
if someone clicked inside the **area** occupied by a button on your canvas.

Here's an example (just click on 'Run code snippet'):

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var image = new Image();
var buttons = [];

function draw(e) {
  let x, y, width, height, path;

  // first button
  x = 20;
  y = 20;
  width = 100;
  height = 20;
  context.drawImage(e.target, x, y, width, height);
  path = new Path2D();
  path.rect(x, y, width, height);
  buttons.push(path);

  // second button
  x = 150;
  y = 20;
  width = 100;
  height = 20;
  context.drawImage(e.target, x, y, width, height);
  path = new Path2D();
  path.rect(x, y, width, height);
  buttons.push(path);
}

function canvasClicked(e) {
  let button;
  for (var a = 0; a < buttons.length; a++) {
    button = buttons[a];
    if (context.isPointInPath(button, e.offsetX, e.offsetY)) {
      console.log("button " + (a + 1) + " clicked");
    }
  }
}

image.onload = draw;
image.src = "https://picsum.photos/id/866/200/300";
canvas.addEventListener("click", canvasClicked);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" style="background-color:grey;"></canvas>
```